# Electron fails when sending a large object with BrowserWindow.webContents.send between renderers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, electron

I am finding impossible to move a large object full of data with

```
console.log('here')
BrowserWindow.webContents.send('test',data)
console.log('again')
```

There's no error message but I don't get the 'again' log.
If I build the data piece by piece, it works with simple data, but when I copy a large portion it doesn't. I cannot reproduce it since the amount of items I have in the object-to-pass is very large (see image), but I JSON-serialize it without problems.

Is there any alternative to pass this variable from a Renderer to another Renderer in Electron?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: How big was your JSON serialization? I was having the same problem, but `JSON.stringify()` told me it was 130MB. Perhaps that counts as "too big"? In my case it made me realize that even I got it to work, it was not doing what I thought it was, and I needed a different approach.

Comment: Yes, I'm facing problems that at the end are related to the size of js objects and/or JSON objects, and as you I have concluded that for those cases I'll need a different perspective

Comment: I just had some error of this sort, fixed it by sending the message to main and then to the respective renderer. I had 2 renderer processes, form and main_window, and i needed to pass a message from form to main_window and it had to be through the main process or else the event was not being consumed. It turned out not to be an issue of size, even though my string size was an imageURL around 1mb long.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the opposite with IPC:

send a sync message from the Renderer and automatically return the message that you want from the Main.

```
var data= ipcRenderer.sendSync("msg", "ping");
```

and

```
ipcMain.on("msg", (event, arg) => {
   event.returnValue = data
})
```

Comment: Your example is on renderer to main, he wants to send to renderer to another renderer.

Comment: Yes but you can use a Renderer process like a main. I tested something similar and it works.

Comment: @emish89 Your response doesn't address the issue of handling large objects through the renderer. The question isn't about sending data in general, but specifically about dealing with large data, as Electron throws errors when attempting to do so.